# How (and whether) to copy and paste on an ssh web interface?

Tags: ssh, vi, clipboard

A web page provides web-based ssh access to a linux machine.  I'm using it one a Windows7 machine.

While editing a file in vi, I want to repeadetly enter the following:

j0nhd0

This (1) goes to the next line, then (2) goes to the beginning of the line, then (3) goes to the next occurrence of the search term, then (4) moves one space to the left, then (5) deletes everything on the line to the left of that point.  The "0" is just because I'm being really cautious.

I thought what I'd do is write the following

j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0j0nhd0

and then copy that and paste it (while *not* in insert mode, of course) and it would do that operation on 15 lines, and then I could stare at it for a few seconds to make sure it didn't do anything wrong, before doing it the next time.  Doing this a couple of hundred times would finish the job in minutes.

***But*** the interface won't let me copy and paste.

So:

- Is there some way I can copy and paste?
- Should I do something intelligent instead?  If so, what?

Comment: It sounds like something you could accomplish with a search-and-replace command à la `:%s/regex/something else/` but it's not clear just from `j0nhd` what it is you're actually doing. By the way, you're missing something from the end of that, for example a `$`, because `d` takes an argument.

Comment: But in any case, why not use a native SSH client. That will surely not have a copy&paste problem.

Comment: @Celada : typo:  I meant j0nhd0

Comment: d0 deletes everything on the line to the left of where the editing cursor is.

Comment: @Celada : Does that sufficiently clarify what I'm doing?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only thing you did is correct the typo, so no, it doesn't. What is it you're trying to do? Maybe delete all text on each line from the beginning of the line up to a specific search term? I don't know, that's what `j0nhd0` *seems* to be doing, but it might depend on the input. Also, it would be handy to know why you can't use a native SSH client and bypass this copy&paste problem altogether. tl;dr: context is useful in a question!

Comment: "delete all text on each line from the beginning of the line up to a specific search term" is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Whether I have or can get a native ssh client is not something that had occurred to me, but maybe I can look into that.......

Comment: OK, I'm thinking about PuTTY.......

Comment: Then it seems like you just want to run `:%s/^.*search-pattern//`

Comment: @Celada : As mentioned in the comment under Marco d'Itri's answer, I've now installed PuTTY, and I still have no ability to copy and paste.  When I try to do it using control-C and control-V, then I get a beeping sound when I hit control-C and a message that says VISUAL BLOCK when I hit control-V.  I also try just highlighting some text and then moving the editing cursor to where I want to paste something and pressing the middle mouse button, but that doesn't do anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've got it working now, via the right mouse button rather than the middle one.

Answer (score 2):

Due to how the browser DOM security model works, this kind of web interface cannot easily access the system clipoboard (or else random web pages could steal the clipboard content).

Your problem is not related to SSH or vi and the intelligent choice would be to use a native SSH client (e.g. Putty).

Comment: I have now downloaded PuTTY and used it to log in to the remote unix machine, and done some editing on the file in question, so all of that works.  But I am still not able to copy and paste. When I try to paste this message appears at the bottom of the screen: VISUAL BLOCK.

Comment: This either means that you pasted an escape character or that you pasted while in command mode.

Comment: Do you mean as opposed to insert mode?  Clearly the thing I was pasting was not something I wanted to insert.

Comment: OK, I've got copy-and-paste working in PuTTY now.  It turns out I needed to use the right mouse button rather than the middle one.

Answer (score 2):

Hey if you use the chrome browser you can install the Secure Shell add on/app its quite simple to SSH over LAN or WAN. And it provides the functionality you are looking for.

Simply copy from a different source and doubletap in the console to paste or if you want to copy from the console highlight the text and it automatically copies the selected text.

If you face problems with connecting somewhere down the line (can happen when you use the same IP for different computers. Try removing allknownhosts from java using CTRL+ALT+J. 
To be more specific: term_.command.removeAllKnownHosts()